# Value of json has multiple data-types (json-shema)

Tags: jsonschema, karate

I have a question about json-schema on karatedsl..
For example i have a json, and one of the key of the json have multiple data-type (for example, it could be #string or #object)
How to validate json that have multiple data-type on karatedsl ??

Example #string :

```
{
  "customer_id":"081234562002",
  "order_id":"",
  "amount":20700,
  "price":20700,
  "created":1560684244,
  "changed":1560684246,
  "data":"Internal Server Error"
}
```

Example #object :

```
{
  "customer_id":"081234562002",
  "order_id":"",
  "amount":20700,
  "price":20700,
  "created":1560684244,
  "changed":1560684246,
  "data":
   {"message": "Internal Server Error"}
}
```

And i have separated json file for validate the json above, like this :

```
{
  "customer_id":"#string",
  "order_id":"#string",
  "amount":"#number",
  "price":"#number",
  "created":"#number",
  "changed":"#number",
  "data":"???"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide two examples of json that must be OK when validated, one with a string and one with an object, and some schema you've already tried please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple options in karate to do this, i can give one quick example here,

```
* match response.myKey == "#? karate.match(_,'#string').pass || karate.match(_,'#object').pass"
```

since we need markers like `#string` i have to use karate.match. you can write any function that return boolean and use it here as a substitute.

read [fuzzy matching](https://github.com/intuit/karate/#fuzzy-matching), [Self validation expression](https://github.com/intuit/karate/#self-validation-expressions) , [Schema Validation](https://github.com/intuit/karate/#schema-validation) from karate docs

Edit: for updated question

replace your `???` as

```
"#? karate.match(_,'Internal Server Error').pass || karate.match(_,{'message' :'Internal Server Error'} ).pass"
```

Comment: But in my case, i have separated json file for json-schema validation, how about that ? btw, i just updated my question